# Filter dataframe contents in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to filter the contents of  a dataframe. If a string is present in a column, those rows have to be stored in a new dataframe

```
    list1 = ['A+B','A']
    list2 = ['1','2']
    df = pd.DataFrame(
        {
         'name':list1,
         'value':list2
        }
    )
    temp_df = df[df.name.str.contains('A')]
    pprint(temp_df)
```

Output obtained:

```
      name value
    0  A+B     1
    1    A     2
```

Desired output:(only those that have an exact match)

```
  name value
0    A     2
```

Any suggestions on how this can be achieved?

Comment: `df.name.eq` instead of `df.name.str.contains` ?

Comment: @jpp It says, `AttributeError: 'StringMethods' object has no attribute 'eq'`

Comment: Are you sure you aren't mistakenly trying `df.name.str.eq` - that won't work.

Comment: @jpp yep, I did the same mistake. df.name.eq works! Thanks a lot

Comment: @jpp df.index.eq doesn't work if I have to filter contents based on ids present in the index column of the dataframe. `AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'eq'` Any suggestions?

Comment: Yes, use `df.index == 'A'` instead.

Answer (score 2):

```
temp_df[temp_df['name'] == 'A']
```